# What would be a good central-tendency algorithm for this?

Tags: algorithm

What algorithm would be good for this?

I have a list of tickets and there is an assigned priority from 1-5, 1 being the lowest and 5 the most important. Arithmetic mean wouldn't do me any good because if a ticket of high priority cancels out a lower one. Mode wouldn't have enough sampling. Median same problem. What would you guys suggest?

**Edit** I'm trying to find a nice(reasonable) score to report the problems for a given set of tickets.

Comment: What are you trying to get exactly?  If the list is just 2 tickets with priorities 3 and 5, what do you want to find?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to measure? Also, a 1 cancelling out a 5 is kinda the point of "central tendency". So mean seems most appropriate.

Comment: This is far too vague to answer.  What are you trying to report?  Some sort of average priority, or a summary of how many and how serious the tickets? What do you mean by a ticket of higher priority cancelling out a lower one?  How do you intend to test for that?  What do you mean by "central tendency"?  With no other information, I'd just sum all the priorities.

Answer (score 1):

A simple bar chart would be the best way to represent your data here (with assigned priority on the x-axis, and the y-axis representing the number of tickets for each priority).  This presentation would pass the *inter-ocular percussion test* (a.k.a. "it hits you right between the eyes").

Comment: I'm not representing things with a graph. I just want a firm number.